# Remove value from a Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a dictionary:

```
public ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<IronportServerStatus>> IronportServerStatusDict = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<IronportServerStatus>>();
```

In the key there are a lot of hosts (string). Lets take for an example this host `abc.def.ghi`. In the value there is a list of `IronportServerStatus`.

The next chase is that I want to remove the the first element of the value [0]. If count >= 10.
After that I want to add the new status which I get all 5 minutes. So the maximum count is 10.

I'm getting a `List<List<IronportServerStatus>>` and removing the first item.
After that I'm adding my new logdata which is a `IronportServerStatus`, this doesn't work also.

```
var result = SystemCore.Instance.IronportServerStatusDict.Where(o => o.Key == host.Host).Select(o => o.Value).ToList();

if (result.Count >= 10)
{
    result.RemoveAt(0);
}

result.Add(logData);
```

Can someone help me please?

---

ANSWER :

```
SystemCore.Instance.IronportServerStatusDict.Where(o => o.Key == host.Host).FirstOrDefault().Value.RemoveAt(0);
SystemCore.Instance.IronportServerStatusDict.Where(o => o.Key == host.Host).FirstOrDefault().Value.Add(logData);
```

Comment: What exactly is your question and what exactly does not work?

Comment: What do you mean by "first" element? Bear in mind that dictionaries aren't ordered...

Comment: What do you want to achieve using this dictionary? May be there is more suitable solution to your problem/

Comment: i know they arnt .. but the list in the dictionary is ordered ..     i want to remove the first item in the value (List) and add a new item if the count of the list is bigger than 10

Comment: well dictionary would be the best because i need the host ... its my primary key. what i could make is 2 list 1 time with hosts and 1 time with status but thats more complicated and not nice ..

Comment: You are removing the value from a dynamically create list (select(...).ToList()). Remove it from the real list.

Comment: okay i got it ...
thats what i want 
                        SystemCore.Instance.IronportServerStatusDict.Where(o => o.Key == host.Host).FirstOrDefault().Value.RemoveAt(0);
                        SystemCore.Instance.IronportServerStatusDict.Where(o => o.Key == host.Host).FirstOrDefault().Value.Add(logData);

this thread can be closed ... sorry guys but thanks for help

Comment: `Dict.Where(o => o.Key == host.Host).FirstOrDefault()` is terrible. Use `Dict[host.Host]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
// Get the list
var result = SystemCore.Instance.IronportServerStatusDict[host.Host];

if (result.Count >= 10)
{
    result.RemoveAt(0);
}

result.Add(logData);

Console.WriteLine(SystemCore.Instance.IronportServerStatusDict[host.Host][0]);
```

Comment: SystemCore.Instance.IronportServerStatusDict[host.Host].Add(logData);

that returns {System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @RamonHämmerle The example is a basic outline of how to do it.  It appears that you do not have the key value set.  Either set it or check for null values.